# Unknown provider error for filter in AngularJS ES6 syntax

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ecmascript-6, angular-filters

I'm having trouble using a filter in my app after bundling and deploying to a remote server. It works fine locally, but if I run my app remotely i get the error:

`"Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: eProvider <- e <- filterByQueryFilter"`

This is my code:

app.js:

```
import myFilters from "./shared/filters";
import myModule from "./myModule";

export default angular.module('app', [
    lots-of-modules...,
    myFilters,])
    .config(defaultRouting)
    .run(["$http", "$rootScope", "$state", function($http, $rootScope, $state){ //code.. }]);
```

index.js(in shared/filters folder):

```
import filterByQuery from "./filterbyquery.filter.js";
import highlightQuery from "./highlightquery.js";
import dateFormatter from "../formatter/dateFormatter";

export default angular.module("my.filters", [])
    .filter("filterByQuery", filterByQuery)
    .filter("highlightQuery", highlightQuery)
    .filter("dateFormatter", dateFormatter)
    .name;
```

another-module.js (where i try to use the filter):

```
export default class anotherModule{

    constructor() {
        this.restrict = 'E';
        this.replace = false;
        this.template = require('./template.html');

        this.scope = {};

        this.controller = AnotherModule;
        this.controllerAs = 'ctrl';
    }
}

class AnotherModule{
    constructor($scope, $filter) {
        this.$filter = $filter;
    }
}

AnotherModule.$inject = [..., "$filter"];
```

Using the filter in the controller:

`res = this.$filter("filterByQuery")(res, this.filterString);`

I'm not really sure what I'm doing wrong here considering it works fine locally. Also, the `highlightQuery` filter works by using the pipe syntax in the `template.html`

Anyone have any idea what is happening here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Minified AngularJS applications should be [properly annotated](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di#implicit-annotation) in order to perform dependency injection.

`filterByQuery` filter factory function wasn't annotated. Since it's contained in separate file, it makes sense to use `$inject` annotation in order to keep it in same module as the function itself. It is the preferable way of annotation in ES6 with ES modules and proposed by [John Papa style guide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/tree/master/a1)

Comment: I forgot to add that to my question but i am injecting `$filter` into `AnotherModule` like this: `AnotherModule.$inject = [..., "$filter"]`. I thought $filter was the filter provider, so i wouldnt need to individually inject the filters i want to use?

Comment: Made it work by moving the filter code into the module that actually needs it(Isn't needed anywhere else). This complies with John Papa rule of not having filters scan all properties of objects.

Thanks for the help though.

Comment: You're welcome. `eProvider <- e <- filterByQueryFilter` error is there because $filter registers filterByQuery *filter* as filterByQueryFilter *service* internally, by adding `Filter` suffix to filter name (you can check how it works in framework sources).

Comment: hmm. I also tried using the filter by doing `$filter('filterByQueryFilter')()` but then it just added another filter to the error message(`eProvider <- e <- filterByQueryFilterFilter`) .

Comment: You don't need to do anything like that, at least in production. When you use `filterByQuery` in template, the compiler gets it like `$injector.get('filterByQueryFilter')`, that's how it works and that's why the error mentioned it like `filterByQueryFilter`.